# How do you download Google Image Search images with Python in 2022?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, download, html-parsing

I'm working on a project which requires **downloading the first *n* results from Google Images given a query term**, and I'm wondering how to do this. It seems that they deprecated their API recently, and I haven't been able to find a good up-to-date answer. Ultimately, I want to

1. **Enter query term**
2. **Save the URLs** for the first n images in a txt file ([example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a1/Mallard2.jpg))
3. **Download the images** from those URLs

I have seen similar solutions that use `Selenium` but I was hoping to use `Requests` instead. I'm not very familiar with HTML parsing, but have used `beautifulsoup` before! Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm currently using **Python 3.8**.

Comment: Google Images uses JavaScript to create the image elements on the page. `requests` and `beautifulsoup` will not work for your situation because they read the raw HTML only and do not run JavaScript. Something like `selenium` will be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @adang1345. To be clear, there's no way to query their databases directly because they deprecated their API? If I use selenium to just scrape the raw URLs for the images, could I use a subprocess to then download the images with cURL?